# Как задать определенный класс родителю, если внутри два больше одного блока с определенным классом?

Tags: javascript

Как задать определенный класс родителю, если внутри него меньше одного блока с определенным классом
Например, если внутри родителя `div class="main-block"` есть два блока `<div class="child">` - класс не задается. Если один - задаем класс выбранному родителю.

```css
.add-class {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="child">Ребенок</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".main-block").forEach(parent => {
  if (parent.querySelectorAll(".child").length <= 1) {
    parent.classList.add("add-class");
  }
});
```

```css
.main-block {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.add-class {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="child">Ребенок</div>
</div>
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="child">Ребенок</div>
  <div class="child">Ребенок</div>
</div>
<div class="main-block">
  No Children
</div>
```